# Ubuntu 23.10 on Samsung book 360 - Keyboard Light

Tags: samsung, keyboard-backlight

I just upgrade to 23.10 in my Samsung (np930qdb-kf6de) laptop and now the backlight of the keyboard doesn't work anymore.With windows 11 and ubuntu 23.04 was working fine.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!